# Using MSVC10 Libraries with MVSC11

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2010

Is there a way to be able to use Visual Studio 2010 libraries with the Visual Studio 2012 Toolset? My project uses freeware libraries that currently are only built with MSVC9 & MSVC10.

I'm already familiar with the Properties->General->Platform Toolset option, but would like to keep it on Visual Studio 2012 (v110) if possible.

Comment: The entire point of the Platform Toolset setting is to get what you are asking for.  Getting all the settings right by hand is **not** worth the trouble and ultimately doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Really? I thought I remember there being an easy workaround. I mean, I know I can use GetProcAddress (the libraries are dlls), but I thought there was a simpler way to do it.